# How to hide the Axis line in stack bar chart high chart

Tags: highcharts, bar-chart, stacked-chart

I want to remove the thin Axis line just after legends in a stacked bar chart. How to achieve it?

[image]

```
 xAxis: {
    categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'],
  lineColor: 'transparent',
   tickWidth: 0,
   tickLength: 0,
   tickColor:'transparent',
   visible:true,
  }
```

Jsfiddle link
https://jsfiddle.net/mehrotrarohit87/51mky0so/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such an option in the API, so you need to hide this grid programmatically.

```
chart: {
    type: 'bar',
    marginLeft: 50,
    marginBottom: 90,
    gridLineWidth: 0,
            events: {
                load() {
                    const chart = this;
                    const ticks = chart.yAxis[0].ticks;
                    ticks[0].gridLine.hide()
                }
            }
},
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/9zpun5ow/

Answer (score 0):

```js
{
   ...
   xAxis: {
      lineColor: 'transparent', // hide x axis line
   }
   ...
}
```